# Find if value is next value is bigger or smaller in R

Tags: r

I have the following R code:

```
y <-round(runif(100, min=0, max=800))
for(i in y) {
  if((i+1)>i) print("bigger") 
  if((i+1)<i) print("smaller")
}
```

I want to know if the next number in the list is bigger or smaller. 
It always prints bigger. I guess because I am doing it wrong.
Any help would be great.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `diff` for this.

```
yd <- diff(y)
ifelse(yd > 0, print('bigger'), print('smaller'))
```

The reason your for loop always prints bigger is because `i` is always less than `i+1`... look at what you're asking... you mean `y[which(y==i) + 1] > i` or something...  If you must use a loop, you can do something like this:

```
for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  if (y[i+1] > y[i]) {
    print('bigger')
  } else {
    print('smaller')
  }
}
```

But, the vectorized version using `diff` will be much more efficient and easier to understand in my opinion.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That is what I have been looking for. Can I also append to a list instead of printing ? Thanks again!

Comment: Just assign the `ifelse` to a vector and stop printing: `res <- ifelse(yd > 0, 'big', 'small')`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a vector in the following way:

```
c("smaller", "bigger")[(diff(y) > 0) + 1]
```